# High-Speed Serial garbled on Linux but works on Windows

Tags: linux, serial-port

On Windows (either native or running on a virtual machine from a Linux host), I can open a serial port in *8N1* mode and my desired speed of **921600 bps**, and an incoming test string arrives fine from an external hardware device: `HELLO WORLD`.

On Linux, however, with same serial configuration I can only get *slightly* garbled text: `H�LLO �OR�D`.

However, lower baudrates (such as *460800 bps*) work fine in both Windows and Linux. So by using *921600 bps* I'm clearly hitting a speed maximum, imposed by some component of Linux.

Why does this happen? **Does Linux have a default limit on serial baudrate?** Is there anything I should configure to enable baudrates higher than *460800 bps*?

Some more details:

- The external device's serial output is connected to the computer via a CH340G-type serial-to-USB converter.
- Tested software is TeraTerm and PuTTY on Windows, picocom, minicom, and screen on Linux.
- Tested O.S. versions are Windows 7, Ubuntu Linux 16.04, and Ubuntu 20.04.
- As mentioned (but it's worth repeating it), the text can be read fine if opening the serial port on Windows running from a VirtualBox virtual machine, from the same Linux host that is not able to cope itself with the mentioned baudrate! I guess this works because VirtualBox simply does a USB device passthrough, so whatever limits Linux has, they don't apply to the virtualized Windows.
- In theory, my Linux seems to support the requested speed: the file `/usr/include/asm-generic/termbits.h` contains the definition for `B921600` (together with lower ones such as `B460800`, and lots of other higher ones that go up to `B4000000`).

Comment: You seem to over-generalize one case. Even if the hardware is the same, the OS and device drivers are different, so it's no wonder that there is a difference. Also, even if the communication speed value is defined in the include file, not all hardware and device drivers can achieve that performance.

Comment: I mentioned the include file because judging from other similar questions, it seems to be important to find the desired baudrate in there. It's clear to me that the HW is able to cope with the speed, so I'd rule it out. That leaves me with SW side: either the concrete app used (tried several, so I'd rule that out too), or the underlying OS, hence my question. I hadn't thought that maybe the problem is in the specific driver and not the Kernel config, though. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll research if there are open issues with the driver for CH340G devices.

Comment: I have a similar problem, also in Windows. CH340B (with build in oscillator), misses characters when looping back characters (RxD connected to TxD), with speeds above 750000 bauds. But no problems with CH340G with external crystal. CH340G works fine with 1.5 MBauds. Since RxD is connected to TxD it should not be a baud rate problem Rx and Tx uses same oscillator, however it seems like it is. If I sends 256 characters out, they are received with errors in most cases, but sometimes they come trough. No problem ever at 1500000 bauds with CH340G types and 12MHz external crystal. Some of the CH340

Comment: Thanks for sharing your observations. Definitely seems an issue of flaky hardware but on the software side of things, the driver also seems to make a big difference. I just accepted the other answer because after this time I'm pretty sure that's what is happening. But your experiments with different versions of CH340 are also enlightening and helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is/was a bug on the CH340 driver.

Apparently, the baud rate error for 921600 bps was more than 7%. I guess that's what you might be experiencing.

I don't have any such devices so I did not research this further and I'm not sure if the patch or patches written to fix this issue ended up on the mainline kernel.

You will have to go [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-usb/patch/20190608051309.4689-1-jontio@i4free.co.nz/) and find out yourself.